# React Native - How generate apk in api 16

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I need to generate the apk in `api 16`, for android 4.1, but is always showing the same error

"ld not get batchedbridge make sure your bundle is packaged properly"

And, not it's not working.

Comment: What command did you try?

Comment: I generate with android studio, and trying emulate with this commands , React native run-android, react-native start --reset-cache

Comment: Theres a bunch of commands you have to run before being able to generate an apk with react-native.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

Comment: this tutorial not working for me.... I need generate for api 16

Comment: It should work... react-native is supported for : Android >= Android 4.1 (API 16) and >= iOS 8.0.